# Wordpress - Order by meta value num

Tags: wordpress

Estou rachando a cabeça com um problema que estou tendo com o Wordpress.

Estou utilizando a ordenação `meta_value_num` para ordenar a partir de uma `meta_key` que vai o valor de alguns imóveis (o valor é colocado sem casas decimais, ex: 100000 (100 mil)). Porém, quando ordenado desta forma, ele não fica na ordem desejada, ex: 100000, 190000, 235000, 1000000, etc.

Segue abaixo o código:

```
$orderby = array('post_type' => 
    'imovel', 'posts_per_page' => 12, 
    'paged' => get_query_var('page'), 
    'meta_key' => 
    'valor_do_imovel', 
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 
    'order' => 'DESC'  
);  

$args = array_merge( $wp_query->query_vars, $orderby );

query_posts( $args );
```

Durante as pesquisas, encontrei um artigo falando sobre usar uma consulta SQL para isso algo como `ORDER BY ABS`, mas meu conhecimento sobre SQL é bem básico.

Comment: Você quer que a ordem seja pelo valor do imóvel? Do menor para o maior?

Answer (score 1):

`orderby` deve ser `meta_value_num` , ou `meta_value`, não o nome da chave.

**Exemplo:**

```
$orderby= array(
    'orderby'  => array( 'meta_value_num' => 'ASC', 'valor_do_imovel' => 'ASC' )
```

**VEJA**: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters

Comment: Testei o código desta forma, e mesmo assim não funcionou.
`$orderby = array(  'post_type' => 'imovel', 'posts_per_page' => 12, 'paged' => get_query_var('page'), 'orderby' => array( 'meta_value_num' => 'DESC', 'valor_do_imovel' => 'DESC' )`    
E agora um erro aparece: Warning: urldecode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in path/wp-includes/query.php. Alguma coisa que ainda estou fazendo errado?